# Key cloak user role mapping

Tags: keycloak

when I POST the user role-mapping REST it gives the following an error response, please give your kind advice to solve this issue.

[http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/{realm}/users/2d6b3636-30da-4bf1-9f1c-54582a348bca/role-mappings/realm](http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth/admin/realms/%7Brealm%7D/users/2d6b3636-30da-4bf1-9f1c-54582a348bca/role-mappings/realm)

Query param - {"id":"dec8e3f4-3a3a-4f5d-8951-c78236134ace","name":"offline_access"}

response - {"error": "unknown_error"}